# How to make a `for` loop work like a `while` loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop, while-loop

I know that there is a way to make a `for` loop work like a `while` loop.

I have this code working :

```
while (BR.BaseStream.Position < BR.BaseStream.Length) // BR = BinaryReader
{
    int BlockLength = BR.ReadInt32();
    byte[] Content = BR.ReadBytes(BlockLength);
}
```

I need the `for` equivalent for this `while` loop..

So Far, I have this :

```
for (long Position = BR.BaseStream.Position; Position < BR.BaseStream.Length; //Don't Know This)
{
    int BlockLength = BR.ReadInt32();
    byte[] Content = BR.ReadBytes(BlockLength);
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? why not use the while look itself?

Comment: @dwerner Not a homework as this is my recent project! Actually i want to transfer all the `while` loops to `for` loops

Comment: there's no real purpose, IMO the while loops are more readable than the for loops.

Comment: @I.am.WritZ as Robert mentioned, there is no real reason, why you should be doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you use one of the Read methods, the BinaryReader increments it's position, so you don't actually need anything in that section.

```
for (long Position = BR.BaseStream.Position; Position < BR.BaseStream.Length; Position = BR.BaseStream.Position)
{
    int BlockLength = BR.ReadInt32();
    byte[] Content = BR.ReadBytes(BlockLength);
}
```

**Update**: I just realized that the `Position` variable isn't ever getting updated. You could either update it at the end of the for loop or in the third section. I updated the code to update `Position` in the third section of the for loop.

Comment: Thanks I was just looking for this!!

Comment: This is the answer in 5 mins!

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why you want to do it, but this is how your for loop should look like

```
int i = 0;
for (; true; )
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    if(++i==10)
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In pseudocode, these two loops are equivalent:

Loop 1:

```
Type t = initialiser;
while (t.MeetsCondition())
{
  // Do whatever
  t.GetNextValue();
}
```

Loop 2:

```
for (Type t = initialiser; t.MeetsCondition(); t.GetNextValue())
  // Do whatever
```

I think you can work out the rest from here.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (long Position = BR.BaseStream.Position; Position < BR.BaseStream.Length; /* If you Don't Know     This, dont specify this. It is Optionl and can be kept blank */)
{
  int BlockLength = BR.ReadInt32();
  byte[] Content = BR.ReadBytes(BlockLength);
}
```